# Yes/ No : Is $f$ is uniformly continious?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is   $f :\mathbb{N}  \cup \{ n + \frac{1}{n}   : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $  defined by    $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text {if }  x \in  \mathbb{N} \\  2 \ \text {if }  x \in  \{ n + \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \end{cases}$  is uniformly continious  ?

## My attempt :

we know  that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete  and $\mathbb{N}  \cup \{ n + \frac{1}{n}   : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is  also complete

Now    complete  map to complete , so i think  it must be uniformly  continious

Is  it true ?

Comment: Are you claiming that every continuous map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: No@anomaly  but  here  map  is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous. Then for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, if $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, and fix $\delta$ accordingly. By the Archimedean principle, we can fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$. Therefore $|n-(n+\frac{1}{n})| = \frac{1}{n} < \delta$, but $|f(n) - f(n+\frac{1}{n})| = 1 > \varepsilon$. This contradicts uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is surely not uniformly continuous.

Consider the two sequences $x_n=n$ and $y_n = n + \frac{1}{n}$. You have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (y_n-x_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$ while $f(y_n) - f(x_n) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. In contradiction with the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of uniform continuity.